# Python. Рекурсия. Что это?

Tags: python, функции, рекурсия

я до сих пор не понял как работает рекурсия

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n - 1)
```

объясните подробнее пожалуйста

Comment: В интернете же полно теории) Посмотрите в книге "Грокаем алгоритмы" главу рекурсия, понятнее чем там я нигде не видел

Comment: (вызов функцией самой себя) называется рекурсией, а сама функция называется рекурсивной.
return n * factorial(n - 1) возвращает ваше значение, вызывая функцию повторно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы вызываете функцию факториала, допустим, с числом `2`:

1. Условие `if n == 0` не выполняется, функция идёт дальше.
2. (`factorial(n - 1)`). Всё повторяется, но с `n`, уменьшенным на 1. Теперь условие снова не выполняется и функция вызывается ещё раз, но с числом `0`.
3. Условие наконец выполнится и вернёт `1`.
4. Потом поднимаемся вверх до функции, вызванной с числом 1. Она вернёт 1 * 1 (т.к. функция ниже вернула 1), и ещё выше передаст свой результат, в данном случае - 1. Потом самая верхняя функция умножает результат предыдущей (1) на 2 и возвращает 2  в основной поток.

---

Вот и получается факториал 2: 1 * 2 = 2

Answer (score 1):

Рекурсия — это когда функция вызывает саму себя изнутри. Ну вот на примере факториала:

```
def factorial(n): # объявление 
    if n == 0: # если n == 0, то...
        return 1 #... то n!=0!=1, верно?
    else: #А если не 0, то...
        return n * factorial(n - 1) #n! = n * (n - 1)! и вызывает эту функцию для значения меньшего на 1.
```

Так понятно?

---

<sub>Кстати если нужен факториал, то лучше так:
`import math
math.factorial(yournumber)`</sub>